# Pandas merge creates unwanted duplicate entries

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm new to Pandas and I want to merge two datasets that have similar columns. The columns are going to each have some unique values compared to the other column, in addition to many identical values. There are some duplicates in each column that I'd like to keep. My desired output is shown below. Adding how='inner' or 'outer' does not yield the desired result.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,2,3,4,5]})

print(pd.merge(df1,df2))

output:
   A
0  2
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  3
5  4
6  5

desired/expected output:
   A
0  2
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

Please let me know how/if I can achieve the desired output using merge, thank you!

**EDIT**
To clarify why I'm confused about this behavior, if I simply add another column, it doesn't make four 2's but rather there are only two 2's, so I would expect that in my first example it would also have the two 2's. Why does the behavior seem to change, what's pandas doing?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [2,2,3,4,5], 'B': ['red','orange','yellow','green','blue']}
)

print(pd.merge(df1,df2))

output:
   A       B
0  2     red
1  2  orange
2  3  yellow
3  4   green
4  5    blue

However, based on the first example I would expect:
   A       B
0  2     red
1  2  orange
2  2     red
3  2  orange
4  3  yellow
5  4   green
6  5    blue
```

Comment: Could you please add a less ambiguous example, say with some different data points?

Comment: I've ran into the exact problem before. This situation will happen when you have duplicates in the column you are trying to merge by

Comment: The answer I provided will help you get around it with a temporary index. You'll get the desired output, but it is not necessarily the most efficient method.

Comment: @Mitch I edited the post to clarify what I'm confused about

Comment: When you use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) without specifying the columns to join on, pandas will by default join on all common columns, which is why you're seeing the different behavior in your two examples.

Comment: I don't think `merge` is actually what you want to use, but the question is still a little unclear.  What do you expect if `df1` and `df2` have different values?  Or will they always be the same?  What columns do you want to perform the "merge" on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1).reset_index()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2).reset_index()

df = df1.merge(df2, on = 'A')
df = pd.DataFrame(df[df.index_x==df.index_y]['A'], columns=['A']).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A
0  2
1  2
2  3
3  4
4  5
```

Comment: Could you add some comment on what that penultimate line is doing?

Comment: What happens if I have two different data set? let say: dict1 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'B':[2,2,3,4,5]}, how do I apply : df = pd.DataFrame(df[df.index_x==df.index_y]['A'], columns=['A']).reset_index(drop=True)
 of your code to it ?

Answer (score 4):

The duplicates are caused by duplicate entries in the target table's columns you're joining on (`df2['A']`). We can remove duplicates while making the join without permanently altering `df2`:

```py
df1 = df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2,2,3,4,5]})

join_cols = ['A']

merged = pd.merge(df1, df2[df2.duplicated(subset=join_cols, keep='first') == False],  on=join_cols)
```

Note we defined `join_cols`, ensuring columns being joined and columns duplicates are being removed on match.

Answer (score 2):

```
dict1 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1['index'] = [i for i in range(len(df1))]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2['index'] = [i for i in range(len(df2))]

df1.merge(df2).drop('index', 1, inplace = True)
```

The idea is to merge based on the matching indices as well as matching 'A' column values.
Previously, since the way merge works depends on matches, what happened is that the first 2 in df1 was matched to both the first and second 2 in df2, and the second 2 in df1 was matched to both the first and second 2 in df2 as well.

If you try this, you will see what I am talking about.

```
dict1 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1['index'] = [i for i in range(len(df1))]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2['index'] = [i for i in range(len(df2))]

df1.merge(df2, on = 'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try df.drop_duplicates() ?

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)

df=pd.merge(df1,df2)
df_new=df.drop_duplicates() 
print df
print df_new
```

Seems that it gives the results that you want

Comment: I know you don't have the rep to comment yet, but this is not an answer.

Comment: Have mercy on the guy

Comment: @AsheKetchum "Mercy" upvoting is probably not healthy. This is not an answer.

Comment: That is True :)

Comment: Actually for this specific problem this is an answer. 
The fact that i use "?" doesnt make it less an answer.
anyway now i can comment :)

Comment: You can only comment on your own answers and questions as of now :P but you'll get there lol.

Comment: @Mitch Either way I think it's not as bad as down voting for no reason :)

Comment: @AsheKetchum There is a reason, though. I don't find this answer useful.

Comment: @Mitch the fact that guides somehow to a direction or something is redundant?

Comment: @Mitch Fair enough, care to elaborate? Otherwise it wouldn't be too unfair to say that the community might not find you useful

Comment: @AsheKetchum I'm thrilled you speak on behalf of the community.

Comment: @Mitch that's irrelevant, the purpose it to provide help and help people improve. You haven't offered any of that.

Comment: @AsheKetchum Because OP's question is still unclear.

Comment: @Mitch The fact that you do not understand it doesn't necessarily make it unclear. I have provided another answer as well. If you bothered to take a look at it and maybe run the code yourself, you will see that it is, in fact, rather clear.

Comment: Hope after my edit, Mr@Mitch has a more clear opinion about my answer

Comment: `drop_duplicates` will not produce the desired result.  The desired result has two instances of 2 in it, and `drop_duplicates` will result in only one instance of 2.

Comment: @Uheq Yes, it is wrong. And your extended example has demonstrated it is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have unfortunately stumbled upon a similar problem which I see is now old.
I solved it by using this function in a different way, applying it to the two original tables, even though there were no duplicates in these. This is an example (I apologize, I am not a professional programmer):

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}
dict2 = {'A':[2,2,3,4,5]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1=df1.drop_duplicates()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
df2=df2.drop_duplicates()

df=pd.merge(df1,df2)
print('df1:')
print( df1 )

print('df2:')
print( df2 )

print('df:')
print( df )
```